# Boost Ionic 2 Performances

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I have made an app for Android using Ionic 2 framework. All goes ok with it, I only would like to boost its performances. I'm debugging it using this command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

On Samsung Galaxy S4 it's a bit slow to load, I tested it out on Samsung Galaxy J7 and there I got better performances, only 3 seconds to open. I have no splash screens so I see a blank screen for a couple of seconds.
How could I avoid this problem?

Comment: Why don't you show a splashscreen? Also building your app using the --prod tag, will Angular make use of the AoT-compiler, which will make your app run slightly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run without --prod tag normally it will slow down your app.
Use this `ionic cordova run android --prod`

Comment: @ManuelGozzi --prod means build for production stage and ready to release